# How Sort Array Date JavaScript dd/mm/yyyy?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

How would I sort an array of dates in chronological order?  For example I have:

```js
var dates = [
    '03/03/2014',
    '01/03/2014',
    '02/03/2014',
    '04/03/2014'
];

sortDates = sortDate(dates);

sortDate(array){
    // ?
    returnt arraySort;
}
```

I'd like the resultant array to look like:

```
[
    '01/03/2014', 
    '02/03/2014',
    '03/03/2014', 
    '04/03/2014'
]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming your date format is consistently `DD/MM/YYYY`:

```js
dates.sort(function(a, b){
    var aa = a.split('/').reverse().join(),
        bb = b.split('/').reverse().join();
    return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});
```

... otherwise you will have to compare [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects if you require more flexibility.

Comment: this works fine..however my date is in MM/DD/YYYY format and if i create two data with the same date then it does not work.Please help.

Comment: There are already answers in this thread that address your specific case.  Notably [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23085497/1238344) - all you'd need to do is swap the order of comparison between indices `1` and `0`.  In fact that's a neater improvement on mine in either case.

Answer (score 7):

Try this (feel free to ask for details) :

```
dates.sort(function (a, b) {
    // '01/03/2014'.split('/')
    // gives ["01", "03", "2014"]
    a = a.split('/');
    b = b.split('/');
    return a[2] - b[2] || a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0];
});
```

Translation of the last line :

```
return          return
a[2] - b[2]     years comparison if year A - year B is not 0
||              or
a[1] - b[1]     months comparison if month A - month B is not 0
||              or
a[0] - b[0];    days comparison
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort.

Answer (score 2):

Just improving @leaf answer as split works on strings so you might get error if the type of 'a' and 'b' is object.

```
dates.sort(function (a, b) {
        a = a.toString().split('/');
        b = b.toString().split('/');
        return a[2] - b[2] || a[1] - b[1] || a[0] - b[0];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do this the easy way.
Works for dates formatted as 'dd/mm/yy' or 'dd/mm/yyyy'.

```
var dates = [
    '03/03/2014',
    '01/03/2014',
    '02/03/2014',
    '04/03/2014'
];

dates.sort( function(c,d){
    var rx = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/;
    var a = Number(c.replace(rx, '$3$1$20000'));
    var b = Number(d.replace(rx, '$3$1$20000'));
    return a > b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1; // for newer on top
    //return a < b ? -1 : a == b ? 0 : 1; // for older on top
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Digigizmo answer works!

in case: dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss 
you can use:

```
list.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a.substring(0, 10).split('/').reverse().join() + replaceAll(':', '', a.substring(11, 20)),
    bb = b.substring(0, 10).split('/').reverse().join() + replaceAll(':', '', b.substring(11, 20));
    return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
});
```

and replaceAll function:

```
function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp(find, 'g'), replace);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arrayDate = ["11/12/2022", "10/11/2021", "20/01/2001", "30/10/2022"];function formatFrToEn(arg){
let [day, month, year] = arg.split("/");
let newFormatDate = [month, day, year].join("/");
return newFormatDate;}let newArrayDate = arrayDate.map( x => new Date( formatFrToEn(x) ) )console.log(newArrayDate)newArrayDate = newArrayDate.sort( (a, b) => Number(a) - Number(b) )function padTo2Digits(num) {
return num.toString().padStart(2, '0');}function formatDate(date){return[padTo2Digits(date.getDate()),padTo2Digits(date.getMonth() + 1), date.getFullYear(),.join('/');newArrayDate = newArrayDate.map(x=>formatDate(x))console.log(newArrayDate)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please enrich your answer with some details and avoid just sending a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

```
dates.sort((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime())
```

If you don't want to sort the elements of an array in place, you can try this code

```
dates.slice().sort((a, b) => new Date(a).getTime() - new Date(b).getTime())
```