# Find the oldest person in the table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Pick the latest date using jQuery</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <table id="targetData">
                <tr><th>Name</th><th>Birthdate</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Test 1</td><td><span>5/9/46</span></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Test 2</td><td><span>3/19/38</span></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#targetData tr td').each(function () {
                $this = $(this);                
                alert($this.find("span").val()); //shows undefined
            });

        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `.text()` instead of `.val()`. Then, you need to parse the date and sort. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084782/how-sort-array-date-javascript-dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: You need to turn those dates into something you can actually work with, so use the date() object in javascript. Then loop through them while comparing them and store the oldest one in a variable until they've all been checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns input values. To get the content of a HTML element use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Answer (score 1):

Change .val() to .html() or .innerHtml().

The span tag does not have a val(). Form objects like input uses the value attribute.