# JQuery Sort elements by date in format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have an array of elements that all have an attribute of dueDate.

However, the date is in dd/MM/yyyy format.

```
<div class="taskItem" dueDate="02/02/2016"></div>
<div class="taskItem" dueDate="20/02/2016"></div>
<div class="taskItem" dueDate="01/02/2016"></div>
```

When I do the following sort;

```
    $('.taskItem').sort(function (a, b) {
        var contentA = Date.parse($(a).attr('dueDate'));
        var contentB = Date.parse($(b).attr('dueDate'));
        console.log(contentA)
        return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
    })
```

I get errors on dates that look like 20/02/2016.  20 Feb 2016. dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: _"I get errors"_ jQuery does not have `.sort()` method

Comment: Sure you must have looked into [Sort Array data dd-mm-yyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084782/how-sort-array-date-javascript-dd-mm-yyyy). Didn't that help?

Comment: I hadn't and looks like that would work.  But what if there was a time component added to the date?  so 20/02/2016 14:00:00?  I guess I would need to cater for that in the sort method.  I was hoping not to have to manipulate my date.

Comment: What is the purpose of using 20/02/2016 instead of 02/20/2016 ?

Comment: Because i live in Australia and we use dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: @griegs Date constructor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Parameters takes values as per `rfc2822`. It will parse date as per your local time format. I don't you can get away from manipulation of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the sort method to, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/cf667nxj/)

```
    function toDate(value)
    {
       var from = value.split(" ")[0].split("/");
       return (new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]));
    }
    $('.taskItem').sort(function (a, b) {
        var contentA = toDate($(a).attr('dueDate')).getTime(); //assuming that attribute value will always be a valid date
        var contentB = toDate($(b).attr('dueDate')).getTime();
        console.log(contentA);
        return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
```

compare **time in milliseconds** rather than whole date string

Comment: This still produces a NAN error on dates that are not MM/dd/yyyy.  So dates that are 02/20/2016 work but dates that are 20/02/2016 do not.

Comment: @griegs updated the parse method to a custom one now, please check

Comment: That would work, but if i have a date of 20/02/2016 13:00:00 it won't.  I guess I was looking at a way to parse the date I had and not manipulate it.

Comment: @griegs you can still change the toDate method by splitting it with space first to get the date part first.

Comment: Yeah I have done that.  Seems backwards to me that i need to brute force my date to fit rather than telling the date engine what my format is

Comment: I think it might help to also use moment.js to simplify date parsing in the sort routine.