# Javascript sort object by dd/mm/yyyy property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

most of my question was answered in this thread: [How Sort Array Date JavaScript dd/mm/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084782/how-sort-array-date-javascript-dd-mm-yyyy)

but was wondering how to do this if the date is in an object, ie

```
var info = [
  {
    name : 'a',
    date : '01/05/2017'
  },
  {
    name : 'b',
    date : '23/12/2013'
  },
  {
    name : 'c',
    date : '22/01/2015'
  }
]
```

no dice with:

```
 (info.date).sort(function(a, b){
      var aa = a.split('/').reverse().join(),
          bb = b.split('/').reverse().join();
      return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
  });
```

thanks!

Comment: If you are ok with adding a library u can try using moment js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since info is an array, apply sort method to info and info.date and inside the comparator function compare date value of each object inside the array. something like this:

```js
var info = [
  {
name : 'a',
date : '01/05/2017'
  },
  {
name : 'b',
date : '23/12/2013'
  },
  {
name : 'c',
date : '22/01/2015'
  }
]

info.sort(function(a, b){
  var aa = a.date.split('/').reverse().join(),
      bb = b.date.split('/').reverse().join();
  return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
  });
console.log(info);
```

Comment: `aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0)` can be simplified to `aa - bb`

Comment: @kukkuz that will not work, aa and bb are actually comma separated strings.