# how to get the most recent dates from array of dates in javascript?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-fns

Here I am receiving the array of dates like this from the API,

```
let dates = ["22/1/2022","22/7/2022","9/10/2018"]
```

From these dates, I need to get the most recent date i.e `22/07/2022`.

I got the below example from a site, This code works correctly only if the date matches the format of `YYYY/MM/DD`.

**CODE**

```
function max_date(all_dates) {
  var max_dt = all_dates[0],
    max_dtObj = new Date(all_dates[0]);
  all_dates.forEach(function (dt, index) {
    if (new Date(dt) > max_dtObj) {
      max_dt = dt;
      max_dtObj = new Date(dt);
    }
  });
  return max_dt;
}
console.log(max_date(["2015/02/01", "2022/02/02", "2023/01/03"]));
```

Can we use some packages like `date-fns` or `momentjs` . to get the desired result despite the date format (or) with JS itself its achievable?

Please let me know your solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Sort Array Date JavaScript dd/mm/yyyy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084782/how-sort-array-date-javascript-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

With date-fns you can do it like

```js
import { max, parse } from "date-fns"

const dates = ["22/1/2022","22/7/2022","9/10/2018"];

console.log(max(dates.map((d) => parse(d, "d/M/yyyy", new Date()))))
// returns Fri Jul 22 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure Javascript for the logic

- Convert strings to dates
- Use timestamps (by `getTime()`) to find max
- Convert that max timestamp back to date or string

```js
const dates = ["22/1/2022", "22/7/2022", "9/10/2018"]

const convertStringToDate = (dateString) => {
  const [day, month, year] = dateString.split("/");

  return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
}

function format(inputDate) {
  let date, month, year;

  date = inputDate.getDate();
  month = inputDate.getMonth() + 1;
  year = inputDate.getFullYear();

  return `${date}/${month}/${year}`;
}

const timestamps = dates.map(date => convertStringToDate(date).getTime())

const max = Math.max(...timestamps)

console.log(format(new Date(max)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting in descending order and returning the first element will do the work.

```js
let dates = ['22/1/2022', '22/7/2022', '9/10/2018'];

const latestDate = (dates) => {
  dates.sort((a, b) => {
    const date1 = new Date(a.split('/').reverse().join('-'));
    const date2 = new Date(b.split('/').reverse().join('-'));

    return date2 - date1;
  });

  // First el will be latest date
  return dates[0];
};

console.log(latestDate(dates));
// Output: 22/7/2022
```